# Как сделать что бы не коммитился уже созданный файл

Tags: git

Есть файл который изменяется постоянно при работе самого приложения и его коммитить не нужно. Как сделать чтоб он не коммитился? .gitignore не вариант, так как файл уже создан.

Comment: Нужно больше контекста. Что это за файл, почему он постоянно меняется, нужен ли он в гите для корректной работы приложения? Может проще его удалить совсем из репозитория и потом добавить в gitignore, раз приложение может работать без изменений в этом файле.

Comment: как раз вполне себе вариант. Добавьте этот файл в .gitignore и не забудьте закомитить  .gitignore.

Comment: Чем вас не устраивает gitignore? Создан - и фиг с ним.

Comment: Нужно добавить в .gitignore **и** сделать `git rm --cached <filename>`, подробности в вопросе по ссылке.

Comment: Очень странные комментарии. Файл конечно же нужен и удалять его нельзя. Приложение без него работать не будет. И нужно чтоб он не коммитился как раз потому что он влияет на работу приложения, так как если я его закоммичу то потом остальным после пулла придётся откатывать изменения в этом файле.

Comment: К тому же на данный вопрос не ответили. Ответили на вопрос почему не игнорируются файлы в .gitignore , я не спрашиваю про .gitignore, читайте внимательнее вопрос перед тем как отвечать.

Comment: > .gitignore не вариант, так как файл уже создан.
Почему не вариант? Как раз таки вариант, добавить созданный файл в .gitignore.

Comment: Давайте поясню. `git rm --cached <filename>` удаляет файл только из коммита, но не с диска. После этого его нужно будет добавить в .gititnore, чтобы не закоммитить снова. Но можно и не добавлять, а просто каждый раз следить, чтобы не закоммитить.

Comment: То есть после `rm --cached` файл останется на диске нетронутым, но в следующий коммит добавится "удаление" этого файла. Т.е. git просто перестанет его отслеживать со следующего коммита.

Comment: Возможно, я неправильно понял вопрос. Если файл создан, но ещё ни разу не был добавлен в коммит, то должно быть достаточно добавить его в .gitignore. Сразу после этого `git status` перестанет показывать изменения в нём.

Comment: Если создан, добавлен (`git add`), но не сохранён в коммит — `git reset filename`. В общем, уточните, что уже делали с файлом?

Comment: предполагаю, что это у вас конфигурационный файл. тогда это дубликат [другого вопроса](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416219/178576)

Answer (score 4):

Предположим, что у Вас имеется следующая папка с файлами (репозиторий) и некоторое количество  коммитов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вы обнаруживаете, что в репозитории лежит файл который совершенно не нужен в проекте.

---

### Исправляем ошибку

#### Ситуация №1. Ненужный файл уже в коммите

Вам потребуется сначала удалить файл из коммитов. Выполняем команду:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f NOOOO.cpp' HEAD
```

[Ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458685/how-can-i-completely-remove-a-file-from-a-git-repository) на оригинал ответа.

#### Ситуация №2. Ненужный файл в состоянии stage

Вы выполнили комманду `git add *` *(например)* и весь репозиторий оказался в состоянии stage. Команда `git status` покажет какие файлы в каком состоянии находятся.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В этой ситуации необходимо выполнить `git rm --cached NOOOO.cpp` или `git reset NOOOO.cpp`. После выполнения команды получим следующий результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

#### Ситуация №3. Ненужный файл в был создан но не попал в поле зрения git

В этой ситуации Вам нужно перейти к следующему пункту :).

---

### Избегаем будущих ошибок

Теперь мы избавились от ненужного файла в коммитах существующих или в области stage. Нужно теперь сделать так, чтобы гит не "видел файл".

Создаем `.gitignore` (на win можно создать через `.gitignore.`). добавляем в него следующую строку и сохраняем:

```
NOOOO.cpp
```

Теперь нужно, чтобы git проиндексировал gitignore. для этого занесем его в новый коммит:

```
git add .gitignore
git commit -m "gitignore"
```

После этого git будет сообщать, что новых файлов нету:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Успешных коммитов!

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите прекратить отслеживать изменения в каком-либо файл в репозитории git, но файл `.gitignore` по каким-либо причинам не подходит — например, файл является довольно специфическим для конкретного проекта и на других компьютерах не возникает (скажем, временные тестовые файлы, полезные только единственному участнику), можно воспользоваться файлом `.git/info/exclude`. Он должен находиться в скрытом внутреннем каталоге git'а, его синтаксис и семантика точно такая же, как и у **gitignore**. Единственное различие — он является локальным для репозитория, его содержимое видно только его владельцу.

Ещё есть глобальная версия этого файла. Она используется для всех репозиториев пользователя и по умолчанию находится в `~/.config/git/ignore` (путь можно изменить настройкой `core.excludesFile`). Тут целесообразно указывать временные файлы вашей любимой IDE, как пример.

Подробнее про обработку всех подобных файлов: классического `.gitignore`, а так же вышеупомянутых `.git/info/exclude` и `~/.config/git/ignore` — смотрите руководство [gitignore(5)](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore). Там же описаны все вариации именования этих файлов.