# Git файлы с разным содержимым в локальном и глобальном репозиториях

Tags: git

Здравствуйте. Никак не могу настроить такую штуку:
У меня в проекте php есть файл с подключением к БД. В нём хранятся данные для этого подключения, то есть хост, пароль и т.д. Я не хотел бы чтоб эти данные находились в репозитории git, но сам файл должен там присутствовать с другими данными. Я пробовал сначала добавлять файл с ложными данными в репозиторий, а потом исключать его из отслеживания, но, я так понял. что если файл уже существует в удалённом репозитории, то удалить его из индекса нельзя? Или как это сделать?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416219/178576

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
git rm file_name
```

Затем прописываете его в `.gitignore`

Comment: Может сразу git rm . прописать? Тогда и добавлять нечего будет...

Comment: Пожалуйста, опишите решение проблемы более детально, чтобы пользователям было легче понять ваш ответ. Для редактирования ответа, нажмите [Edit]. Так же можете ознакомиться с советами о том, [как написать хороший ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). - [Из очереди проверок](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/147554)