# Как скачать файл с Github только один раз и затем игнорировать изменения в нём?

Tags: git, github

Я хочу создать конфигурационный файл с паролями.
Каждый программист делает копию проекта, настраивает этот файл и затем, работает в обычном режиме.
Этот же файл должен быть .ignore ,но в то же время должен существовать и не реагировать на изменения.
Такое можно сделать?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416219/178576

Comment: Лучше организуйте конфигурационные файлы так, чтобы в репозитории их вообще не было и каждый программист создавал их сам, например положив config.example.cfg вместо самого конфига

Answer (score 3):

1. Создать файл `super-secret-passwords.cfg.orig`
2. Добавить файл `super-secret-passwords.cfg` в игнор, но читать из приложения его.
3. После клонирования копировать файл `super-secret-passwords.cfg.orig` в `super-secret-passwords.cfg` и вносить пароли.