# Файлы конфигурации в ветках

Tags: git, git-commit, git-branch

Доброго времени суток, стоит непростая задача с GIT:

Проект состоит из ядра и конфига.

Есть главная ветка *master*, которая содержит **ядро** и **конфиг**, и несколько веток с **конфигами** для разных вариаций проекта.

Т.е. проекты отличаются друг от друга **только** **конфигами**.
Ядро **не** может работать без конфига, ну и конфиг без ядра.

Ядро разрабатывается отдельно и одинаковое для всех проектов.

Проекты разрабатываются, "подгружая" ядро из ветки ядра.

Грубая схема:

```
===master===
[Файлы ядра]
config.cfg (базовый конфиг. Он не должен подгружаться)

===проект===
config.cfg (конфиг проекта. Он не должен заменяться)
[Файлы ядра] (Они должны подгружаться) из master'а
```

P.S>Говорили, что это можно как-то сделать с помощью сабмодулей...

P.P.S> Без дополнительных репозиториев

(Прошу отредактировать вопрос, если знаете, как это объяснить проще и конкретнее)

Comment: Может просто в игнор конфигурации добавить и просто на нужной машине его только и добавлять?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб
Гы. Конфиги должны лежать в ветке...
Т.е. при pull с другой машины, конфиги должны подгружаться

Comment: Если честно, сам слабо представляю, как оно должно работать...
Но компиляция происходит на другой машине и там нужно подгружать ядро+конфиг проекта

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416219/git-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b

Comment: @insolor спасибо, но там совершенно другой случай

Answer (score 1):

1. config.cfg добавляете в игнор.
2. создаете каталог в котором храните отдельные конфиги (config_dev.cfg, config_prod.cfg и т.д.)
3. на конкретных машинах делаете симлинк с именем config.cfg на нужный.

Comment: кстати, а какой язык/компилятор/сборщик может просто параметры сборки настроить?

Comment: стоит добавить, что симлинк нужен относительный (relative)

Comment: @ВоробьевАлександр нет, сборщик настроить не вариант

Comment: @ВоробьевАлександр
1. Какой из config'ов?
2. Так эти конфиги должны быть в GIT'е, что бы на всех машинах были одинаковые версии
3. А разрабатывать эти конфиги как? Тут главный смысл в том, что конфиг нужно отлаживать, т.е. запускать с ядром.

Comment: Вы же сами сказали, что все конфиги должны быть в git.Версии на разных машинах могут быть разные (зависит от активной ветки и коммита). А используемый при компиляции зависит от симлинка на конкретной машине.

Comment: @ВоробьевАлександр не совсем, версии на всех машинах - одинаковые (иначе смысл использовать git?). Конфиги разрабатываются в отдельных ветках. Т.е. для разработки конфига нужно ядро, которое подключается из ветки ядра.

Comment: Git позволяет иметь "вложенные" репозитории. Пусть один репозиторий ядра, другой для конфигов. В каждом свой gitignore.
У вас конфиг относится к конкретному проекту? Есть несколько проектов. Каждый из которых использует общее ядро. Т.е. у вас отдельные репозитории для каждого проекта (в которых хранится конфиг), но из них можно (тут уже от деталей вашей внутренней кухни) исключить ядро. И один репозиторий для ядра.

Comment: @ВоробьевАлександр P.P.S>

Comment: Как я понял, ТЗ на гите реализовать невозможно?

Comment: На сколько я знаю нет. Вообще с трудом представляю сложившуюся у вас ситуацию. По сути конфиг должен быть разный но одинаковый. Параметры сборки проекта менять нельзя, ни чего нельзя. А хочется это сделать средствами системы для этого не предназначенной. Если и можно то только какими то безумными костылями. Единственное, что могу предложить копать в строну хуков. на post-checkout когда меняете ветку - запускайте некий скрипт, который меняет конфиг на нужный

Comment: Вообще самый правильный вариант: это настраивать систему сборки проекта. На мой взгляд выкрутасы с git это костыль, который говорит о неправильном процессе разработки.... ИМХО

Comment: @ВоробьевАлександр я вижу 1 вариант: отмена слияния файла конфига... Т.е. в каждой ветке есть конфиг с какой-то версией ядра... При компиляции выполнить слияние ветки ядра с текущей, исключая конфиг...