# Удалить конкретный коммит с центрального Git репозитория

Tags: git, bitbucket

Здравствуйте!
У меня такая проблема с pull запросом на реальный сервер.
Дано: коммит, в котором зафиксировано удаление конфигурационных файлов (я их потом добавлял в игнор лист). 
При pull запросе на реальный сервер эти файлы тоже удаляются, а мне хотелось бы, чтобы на реальном сервере они остались не тронутыми.
Как можно исправить ситуацию?

Мои шаги были вроде такими:

1) на сервере инициализирован репозиторий и все файлы были залиты на bitbucket. Естественно, что там появились и конфигурационные файлы.

2) Репозиторий был склонирован на локальном компьютере и в файл ignore были добавлены конфигурационные файлы, но git их всё равно отслеживал.

3) Тогда были выполнены команды

git rm -r --cached .

git add .

git commit -m ".gitignore is now working"

4) этот коммит был залит на bitbucket и в нем эти файлы пометились как удаленные.

5) теперь при попытке залить какие-либо изменения на сервер через pull, на сервере эти файлы также удаляются чего не хотелось бы.

Comment: У вас понятия все перепутались. Файлы либо в системе контроля версий, либо нет. Вы хотите странного. Держите ваши конфигурационные файлы в другом месте, потом при deployment уже совмещайте.

Comment: Я дополнил своё описание. Как можно исправить ситуацию?

Comment: Ответ остаётся прежним — разберитесь с кашей в голове.

Comment: Конфиг-файлы (config.ini и т.п.) принято держать вне гит, чтобы каждый разработчик мог их настроить под себя. В гит можно положить образцы настроек (sample.config.ini) для изучения. Налицо [XY-проблема](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/213987) и отрицание принятых практик.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [git и конфигурационные файлы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416219/git-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b)

Comment: О боже мой. Вот так всегда на русских форумах, все ответы вокруг да около, а где совет как исправить проблему? Я понимаю, что в следующий раз так делать не нужно.