# Как хранить и управлять конфигурационными файлами проекта в Open Source?

Tags: java, git, github, config

Допустим я делаю веб-приложение, которое использует какой-то API или просто работает с базой данных. Я хочу выложить исходные коды приложения в открытый доступ, но как быть с секретными данными, такими как ключи API, пароли к БД и SMTP?

Я могу написать в readme, что конфигурационный файл такого-то типа вам придется создать руками, но хочется собирать проект и отправлять его в продакшн из git репозитория, который хостится, например, на github.

Особенно интересно было бы прочитать ответы на примере Java технологий, потому что я делаю Java веб-приложение.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [git и конфигурационные файлы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416219/git-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b)

Comment: а также: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428483/178576

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В самом общем случае, в общедоступный репозиторий кладут конфиг-файл, в котором нет паролей и хостов, которые вы не хотите скомпрометировать. Пишут какие-нибудь дефолтные значения (например, `example.com` или `12345`), в комментариях или документации описывают, что нужно подставить, чтобы работало. Реальные же конфиги держат в недоступном для посторонних месте (например, приватном репозитории) и подкладывают во время деплоя в продакшн.

Обычно конфигурацию стараются вынести из архива с приложением, чтобы его не перепаковывать его при деплое. Это можно сделать как захардкодив имя конфига, и ожидая его найти в папке с приложением или каком-нибудь другом заранее известном месте, так и требуя от пользователя указывать путь к конфигу в аргументах JVM при запуске.

Также распространённым вариантом является частичное переопределение конфигов (которое очень хорошо работает, если конфиги - файлы properties). В архиве с приложением лежит полный конфиг, в котором все секретные параметры заменены дефолтными значениями, а извне лежит конфиг, в котором указаны реальные значения только для секретных параметров. Приложение сначала читает конфиг, который в него зашит, потом - внешний, и переопределяет совпадающие параметры. Так мы избавляемся от необходимости полностью копировать конфиг в приватный репозиторий и постоянно синхронизировать его с публичным.

Если ваше приложение написано на Spring Boot, то всё это вы получаете из коробки. Spring Boot умеет подтягивать [внешние конфиги](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) из кучи мест и позволяет управлять загружаемыми конфигами при помощи профилей.

Также в семействе проектов Spring есть [Spring Cloud Config](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/), работающий в связке с [Spring Cloud Config Server](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html). Сервер конфигурации может подтягивать конфиги из множества источников (в том числе из репозитория Git) и отдавать их через REST API. Клиент (ваше приложение) подтягивает значения свойств через стандартные аннотации Spring `@Value` совершенно прозрачно для программиста. Такая связка позволяет очень удобно управлять настройками сразу нескольких окружений (например, один сервер конфигурации может обслуживать и тестовые, и продакшн сервера, хотя это и нежелательно) или нескольких инстансов задеплоенного приложения. Такое решение изначально разрабатывалось под микросервисную архитектуру, поэтому такую связку имеет смысл поднимать, если у вас инстансов приложения больше одного, и деплой полностью автоматизирован.

А ещё Spring Cloud Config умеет [шифровать конфиги](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/single/spring-cloud-config.html#_encryption_and_decryption). Такие конфиги можно (хотя и не рекомендуется) выкладывать в публичный репозиторий, а при деплое просто подкладывать ключ для расшифровки (вот его ни в коем случае светить не нужно).

Конечно, всё вышеописанное можно реализовать и без Spring, но Spring очень сильно всё облегчает.