# Проблема с игнорированием файлов

Tags: git, github

В локальном и удаленном репозитории некоторые файлы должны отличаться. Но добиться этого не получается.

Пробовал добавлять файлы в файл .gitignore - все равно при комите они комитятся и при отправке на удаленный отправляются.

Не пойму в чем дело, прошу помочь. Требуется исключить проверку изменения этих фалов на локальном, либо как-то запретить отправлять их на удаленный.

Например есть файл по пути application/config/config.php. Я настраиваю его для удаленного репозитория, делаю комит и отправляю (git push). После чего я изменяю его для локального проекта. И теперь нужно чтоб он не загружался измененный на удаленный репозиторий.

Пробовал убрать его из индексации через git rm --cached path/to/file, но тогда при комите и отправки на удаленный этот файл удаляется на удаленном, а на локальном остается.

Причина почему нужно обязательно оставить файлы на удаленном репозитории нетронутыми: на сервере стоит развертывание с этого репозитория. То-есть сервер подтягивает все файлы с репозитория и разворачивает их у себя.

Comment: После добавления в .gitignore убрали ли вы эти файлы из индексирования? `git rm --cached myfile`

Comment: Это неправильно. Вам стоит организовать работу с файлами так, чтобы в этом не было необходимости. Например, если это какой-то файл конфигурации, то стоит завести example-файл, который и будет лежать в репозитории, а настоящий файл конфигурации отдельный в .gitignore и в репозитории вообще не существует

Comment: Просто на сервере стоит развертывание через удаленный репозиторий

Comment: Нашел ответ на https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879783/git-doesnt-ignore-2-specifically-named-files

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [git и конфигурационные файлы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416219/git-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b)