# Свой .gitignore для каждой ветки

Tags: git, github, gitignore

Есть две ветки на GitHub: **Master** и **Develop**.

Структура проекта:

```
-dist
-src
-package.json
-webpack.config.js
```

Я работаю с develop и стабильные версии merge request'ом отправляю в Master. При этом мне не нужно, чтобы папка src, package.json и конфиг webpack попадали в Master.

Как правильно организовать такую структуру?

Comment: а почему в мастер не должны попадать а в другие ветки должны? Выглядит так, как будто у Вас гит в проде.

Comment: @KostiantynOkhotnyk master у меня деплоится с гита сразу на сайт по команде. Не очень хочется иметь сурсы в папке сайта. Конечно, их можно закрыть сервером, но можно и руками это всё делать в таком случае. Поэтому интересует способ исключения нужных файлов и папок из master'а.

Comment: Есть нормальные способы разворачивания типа gitlab. Но если хочется извращений, вот оно: сделать хук на [pre-merge в master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102714/how-would-i-write-a-pre-merge-hook-in-git), в котором делать удаление `src`. Не уверен, что это сработает, но попробуйте

Comment: @Idon'tknowhowithappened суть в том, что иметь гит на проде уже уязвимость. Если Вас хакнуть, то сделать `git fetch` проблемы не составит, и все усилия будут помножены на ноль. По хорошему у вас должна быть какая-то CI, которая копировала бы папку dist из dev на прод.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [git и конфигурационные файлы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416219/git-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b)