# Как правильно скрывать всякие ключи в проекте при загрузке в github?

Tags: android, git, github

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно скрывать всякие ключи/секреты в проекте при загрузке в github?

Comment: не загружайте их в гитхаб. это самый правильный способ

Comment: чуть более общий вопрос практически о том же самом: [git и конфигурационные файлы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416219/178576)

Answer (score 1):

Если вы собираете проект локально для тестов (пример основан для проекта на Python), то основные переменные окружения, которые могут содержать ключи доступа к облачным сервисам - хранится в `.env` файле.

Он в свою очередь должен быть добавлен в `.gitigrnore` файл, это укажет `git` не добавлять любые изменения, связанные с ним в историю коммитов.

Старайтесь избегать прямого указания приватной информации в самом коде проекта.

Общий совет, держать пароли и другие данные, которые не должны быть опубликованы в отдельном файле который читается программой при локальной отладке

*.env*

```
DB_PASSWORD=123
DB_USER=user
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=5432
```

*.gitignore*

```
.env
```

**Ссылки**

- https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore