# Git, автоматический merge без конфликтов в одном файле

Tags: git, github, redux, branch, merge

подскажите, вот есть два фронтэнд разработчика, есть несколько редюсеров. Композиция редюсеров хранится в одном файле reducer.js.

```
const reducer = combineReducers({
reducer1,
reducer2,
reducer3,
})
```

У первого разработчика получается

```
const reducer = combineReducers({
reducer1,
reducer2,
reducer3,
reducerDev1
})
```

У второго разработчика получается

```
const reducer = combineReducers({
reducer1,
reducer2,
reducer3,
reducerDev2
})
```

Каждый разработчик пишет свою часть и свой редюсер, но с композицией они работают вместе. При мердже веток в дев, остается результат LAST branch merged в reducer.js:

```
const reducer = combineReducers({
reducer1,
reducer2,
reducer3,
reducerDev2 // если его ветка последняя в пулл реквесте - результатом будет это.
})
```

Что делают в таких ситуациях? Руками делает мердж ответственный за гит? Конфликта это не вызывает.

Comment: Бить по рукам второго разработчика. По умолчанию git merge тут останавливается с конфликтом и разработчик должен его исправить.

Comment: Ну вот не останавливается.

Comment: Может у него какой-нибудь git rerere вмешивается? https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416219/178576

Comment: rerere вообще не было такой команды, я смотрел, надо ковырять дальше по-ходу