# git - исключить конкретную строку из отслеживания

Tags: git, github, безопасность, gitlab

Есть ли у git'а возможность исключить конкретную строку/слово/символ из отслеживаемого, что-то вроде занесения ее в .gitignore.

Например, есть файл с конфигом, в нем есть какой-то секретный токен, надо запушить на гитхаб этот файл только без секретного токена.

В файле:

$telegramToken = "dasfdasflasdfls";

Улетит на гитхаб:

$telegramToken = "";

Comment: Храните секретный токен в отдельном файле и добавьте этот файл в .gitignore — это в миллион раз лучше, чем пытаться накостылять с игнорированием конкретных строк

Comment: я думаю нагуглит можно всякое в том числе и это. Есть целые статьи почему этого делать не стоит. Хорошее решение создавать конфигурационные файлы (прописать пути, которые при деплое будут оличаться, например), а для данных с паролями и токенами хранить их в отдельных окружениях/файлах и не писать их в коде

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [git и конфигурационные файлы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416219/git-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b)

Answer (score 1):

Обычно делается примерно так:

- допустим, есть папка `config`
- в ней создаётся папка `dist`
- в папку `dist` помещаются фейковые конфиги или конфиги для локальной разработки
- папка `dist` коммитится
- далее, на проде, вы копируете нужные конфиги из папки `dist`, например, `mail.php` в родительскую папку (`config`)
- файлы из папки `config` (которые мы скопировали из `dist`) подключаются в одноимённых файлах из папки `dist` и переопределяют значения параметров (в PHP например это делают с помощью `array_merge()`); если какого-то параметра нет, то он, соответственно, будет браться из одноимённого файла из папки `dist`
- файлы в папке `config` добавляются в `.gitignore`

---

А если очень хочется именно строку, то в IDE-хах есть такие фичи. Например, в PhpStorm можно на вкладке Git перенести изменённый файл в другой «Change List» и он не будет добавляться в `stage`, хотя другие его изменения — будут.

Comment: если предложенное вами принципиально отличается от всех ответов на [«канонический» вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416219/git-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b), то стоит написать ответ там, а не здесь.