# Как в git выполнить обновление всех файлов за исключением указанного?

Tags: git, github, merge

На гитхабе лежит проект. В нём есть некий файл application.properties. В то же время этот файл существует локально в проекте, но с отличным от того что на гитхабе содержимым. Как сделать так чтобы при слиянии обновились все файлы, отличные от локальных за исключением этого файла application.properties?

Comment: `application.properties` это конфиг какой-то? Если да - добавлять его надо в .gitignore, и "удалять" с гита, там, к примеру, можно переименовать его в `application.properties.example` чтобы был пример как он должен выглядеть. А уже где Вам надо - на локалке, на серваке добавлять себе файл `application.properties` с нужными настройками - его будет игнорировать гит.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно изначально данный файл поместить в `.gitignore` и тогда ни при каких слияниях он не будет затронут

Comment: В таком случае он удаляется при git pull

Comment: Не правда. Он не удаляется никогда. Потому что гит иего **игнорит**. Для этого и придуман `.gitignore`, чтобы не трогать файлы, которые не надо трогать при любых операциях

Comment: А храниться в прежнем виде на гитхабе он будет?

Comment: Все файлы, которые **изначально** добавлены в `.gitignore` в дальнейшем не будут затронуты ни при pull ни при merge.

Comment: Эта рекомендация сама по себе правильная, но тут не очень полезная. Не отвечает на вопрос, и главное говорит "не делайте так", но не показывает как решить изначальную предполагаемую проблему хранения и использования разных конфигураций.

Comment: @RomanKonoval пока не знаю степень тяжести у ТС. Может это пока только предварительный вопрос, чтобы потом воспользоваться ответом. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯   Пусть будет)

Answer (score 0):

Делаете сначала слияние без коммита, потом отменяете изменение в этом конкретном файле и комитите:

```
git checkout target-branch
git merge --no-commit branch-to-merge
git reset HEAD path/to/you/application.properties
git checkout path/to/you/application.properties
git commit
```

Лучше, конечно, изменить подход к хранению конфигурации. [Тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416219/git-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B) много рекомендаций на эту тему. Вы похоже используете spring boot. Для него можно очень просто [подсунуть](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.8.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files) свой локальный файл конфигурации, который не лежит в системе контроля версий.