# Как сделать, чтобы один файл был на одном удаленном сервере, а на другом удаленном сервере - нет

Tags: git

Для деплоя бота на Heroku нужно создать файл Procfile. Как грамотнее и правильнее сделать, чтобы Procfile был на Heroku, а на Github - нет.

Comment: А зачем? Что плохого, что нужный для запуска файл хранится в системе контроля версий? Не пытаетесь ли вы таким образом решить проблему хранения параметров конфигурации в системе контроля версий? Если так - то это дубликат, обсуждалось неоднократно. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416219/git-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b

Comment: @RomanKonoval Да, вы правы, это то, что мне нужно. Спасибо за вашу помощь.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [git и конфигурационные файлы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416219/git-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b)