# git hook для удаления части кода

Tags: git

Можно ли написать git hook или нечто подобное, что бы при комите не комитились строки с именем пользователя и пароля: Например комитим файл с двумя строчками:

```
login = "root"
password = "root"
```

И после выполнения хука оставались такие строчки:

```
login = ""
password = ""
```

Comment: в коде не должно быть паролей. Создайте конфигурационный файл и внесите его в гитигнор, тогда и хуки не понадобятся.

Comment: ну так я думаю, что автор с Вами согласен. И он хочет это хоть чуточку автоматизировать.  Хук, что бы не пропускало коммит написать можно, вопрос в том, как понять, что коммитят пароль. Тут я даже не знаю

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-Git-%D0%90%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8B-Git Фильтр clean, но вообще это довольно стрёмная технология

Comment: @Эникейщик Бывают случаи когда нельзя создавать конфигурационные файлы, вроде бы с clean дельно выглядит, будем смотреть

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [git и конфигурационные файлы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416219/git-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b)